# Model ->view update

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am new to ASP.NET MVC concepts.

The values address shown in the view are supposed to be changed based on the dropdown value selected. But it shows the previous/initial values every time.

On dropdown, I call a function in jQuery `showMyProfile()`. And this fn pass values to action method `LoadProfile()` returning a view `_CandDtls.cshtml`. Now the updated or queried results are assigned to the properties in `objonline_application_model` and it is passed to the view. But the view still shows the old values.

Should I assign values via Jquery for each fields or the view itself should get changed when model is passed to it automatically.

Right now I update the fields using Jquery from the success call but is that the right way? Please help. Because there are too many fields supposed to be updated. For security issues, I could not post them.

JS:

```
function showMyProfile(RID, CID, AID) {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: absURL('CandidateApp/LoadMyProfile'),
        data: { RID, CID, AID },
        'async': false,
        datatype: 'json',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        beforeSend: function () {
            dvajaxloadshow();
        },
        success: function (message) {
            //Personal details fields

            //Address related fields
            $("#txtAdd1").val(message.add1);
            $("#txtAdd2").val(message.add2);
            $("#txtAdd3").val(message.add3);
            $("#cmbPerCountry").val(message.country_id);
            $("#cmbPerState").val(message.state_id);
            $("#cmbPerCity").val(message.city_id);
            $("#txtPin").val(message.pin);
            $("#txtCommAdd1").val(message.commAdd1);
            $("#txtCommAdd2").val(message.commAdd2);
            $("#txtCommAdd3").val(message.commAdd3);
            $("#cmbCommCountry").val(message.commCountry_id);
            $("#cmbCommState").val(message.commState_id);
            $("#cmbCommCity").val(message.commCity_id);
            $("#txtCommPin").val(message.commPin);

        },
        complete: function () {
            dvajaxloadhide();
        },
        error: function () {
            dvajaxloadhide();
        }
    });
}
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult LoadMyProfile(long formid = 0, long id = 0, long docid = 0, long recruit_id = 0, long cand_user_id = 0, long desig_id = 0,
                                          long post_id = 0, string recruit_end_date = "", long application_id = 0)
{
    online_application_model _objonline_application_model = new online_application_model();
    _objonline_application_model = _objCandidateOnlineApplicationRepo.GetSelectedCandidateDetails(cand_user_id, docid, recruit_id, post_id, application_id);
    //_objonline_application_model have latest values set                            
    return Json(_objonline_application_model, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

HTML or view:

```
@model NOIT.ViewModels.online_application_model
<td>
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.commAdd1, new
                        {
                            @class = "txt",
                            @id = "txtCommAdd1",
                            @data_ele_msg = "Communication Address1 Required.",
                            @data_ele_req = "true",
                            @maxlength = "100"
                        })
</td>
```

Comment: Couple of notes:  1) Your LoadMyProfile returns JSON, not a View; your code doesn't appear to use `_CandDtls.cshtml`.     2) *"and it is passed to the view"* - it's passed to the browser (or more specifically the ajax success:) - don't mix terms "view" (browser) with "View" (cshtml)   3) using ajax your page won't "automatically" update - you need code to do so; you're using `$("#id").val(val)` to update.

Comment: The "Right Way" depends on your requirements. Your solution is ok - but the more fields you have the more unhelpful this is as you need the fields to exist in your initial View and js to update them - so not ideal.   You could instead `return PartialView(_objonline_application_model);` and have a `LoadMyProfile.cshtml` Razor *partial* view - the ajax can then be converted to `success: function (message) { $("'profile").html(message); }` - this would replace the html in your browser with the html from the partial view - so you don't need the fields in the initial load, just `<div id='profile'>`

Comment: Thanks alot for this, $("'profile").html(message);  Worked for me. You made my day.